# Cannot get Key Value of Dictionary in Jinja2 Template

Tags: python, jinja2

Let's say I have two list of dictionary like below:

`FeeDict = [{u'100': u'Booking Fee'}, {u'101': u'Penalty Fee'}]`

`ChargeObj = ([{'ChargeAmount': 50.0, 'KeyCharge': u'101'}, {'ChargeAmount': 150.0, 'KeyCharge': u'100'}], [{'PromotionAmount': 0.0, 'KeyCharge': u'101'}, {'PromotionAmount': 0.0, 'KeyCharge': u'100'}], [{'TotalCharge': 200.0, 'TotalPromotion': 0.0}])`

I tried to get key value of both variables and arrange it just like below:

Booking Fee : 150.0

Penalty Fee : 50.0

So I tried my code in `jinja2` like this:

```
<table>
    {% for row in ChargeObj %}
        {% set key = row[0]['KeyCharge']|string %}  <!-- 100 or 101 -->
        {% set desc = FeeDict[0][key] %}            <!-- Booking Fee or Penalty Fee -->
        {% set amt = row[0]['ChargeAmount'] %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{desc}}</td>
            <td>{{amt}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

The problem is that `FeeDict[0][key]` not return a value as I expected above. However, it will return value if I assigned fixed `key` to it say `FeeDict[0]['100']`, but why not `key` from `FeeDict` ?

I thought probably that `key` required be to a `string` not `number` so I tried `row[0]['KeyCharge']|string` but still not help.

What's wrong with that? How can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: `FeeDict[0][key]` , `key` not `unicode` type, add a `validator` . Like this : `FeeDict[0][(unicode(key) if type(key) != unicode else key)]`. my opinion don't touch `encoding` if you got `input_encoding == output_encoding` condition.

Comment: @dsgdfg, thanks for your comment. `type` and `unicode` is not recognized in jinja2.

Comment: `FeeDict = [{u'100': u'Booking Fee'}, {u'101': u'Penalty Fee'}]` reference point. Return `FeeDict[0].keys()` for test, you will be see `What I meant`

Comment: @dsgdfg I might understand what you meant. Loop `FeeDict` to get its key/value in `python` view first and pass them to jinja2 ?

Comment: Opss , convert your  table to a `string`, The link between the variables may be lost.(yes if can, see data is okay)

Comment: Does it? I test putting outside of table `<tr><td></td></tr>` it still does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159497/discussion-between-dsgdfg-and-houy-narun).